# Do stored procedures improve performance?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am newbie to web development.

I have an application server where my ASP.NET code resides. My application server communicates to a MySQL instance which is on a different server. 
I was wondering, whether it is a good practice to move the computation from the application server to the database server by having a Stored Procedure with Views or should I just move on with all logic kept in application server and query the database only to retrieve data from tables directly without having stored procedures and views.

Comment: This decision shouldn't be affected by 'performance' without a clear use-case of when/what should would 'improve'. (Most benefits will come just from a good schema / transaction design and correct indices using SPROC/BULK/etc techniques and optimizing queries as indicated from actual performance numbers.) And I do not feel like entertaining the SPROC-vs-NO-SPROC debate this morning.

Answer (score 3):

I am a strong advocate of putting database logic *into* the database and not splitting it between the application and the server.  This means that I prefer to wrap *all* database calls in stored procedures and views.

The driving reasons are maintenance, security, and functionality, not performance, although performance is often better on the server side.

The number one reason is to isolate the application from changes in the underlying data structure.  So, if the data structure changes, the application does not (always) break.

Other reasons the come to mind:

- The same logic gets used for the same thing.  That is, one piece of code doesn't define "foobar" one way and another "foobar" another way.
- Auditing and logging are implemented within stored procedures rather than using triggers.
- Database tables are off-limits to all users, unless they go through the defined interface.
- A newer version and older version can often co-exist.

Admittedly, for a one-off, quick-and-dirty application these issues may not be important.  However, I think it is a good idea to have well defined interfaces (APIs) between different components of a system, and databases and the application layer are a prime example where such APIs are quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Gordon on separating out a "layer" of code between the application and the actual database.  I dispute how practical Stored Routines are at such.

- PHP (etc) is far more expressive than SProcs.
- One SProc can execute multiple queries faster because it is closer to the server.  This can be an overwhelming performance gain if the client and server are on opposite sides of the country.
- Error checking is clumsy in SProcs.
- PHP recompiles only when the code changes; SProcs recompile once per connection; Perl always recompiles; etc.
- VIEWs are sometimes poorly optimized, so I avoid them.

The secret to a good design for the "layer" is in the compromise between the forces tugging on either side.  One example: Can you completely hide a schema change from the app?  Even if you split one table into two?

A really bad example was when the UI did pagination by using page numbers.  The layer thought in terms of OFFSET and LIMIT, and fed that to the MySQL back-end.  Then came an item will 216K pages (Yes, that many!)  They found out that OFFSET+LIMIT is not a good way to implement "next page", but fixing it required a changes to all layers of the system.

Comment: So, how did they change the OFFSET LIMIT ? I still use it, I don't understand.

Comment: More on pagination and `OFFSET`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination .  Possible example:  the URL for the page 5 is `http...?page=5`; the code constructs `SELECT ... LIMIT 40, 10` where 40=(5-1)*10 and 10 is number of items per page.